# CakePHP is not always returning foreign characters

Tags: mysql, cakephp, cakephp-2.3

The database collation is set to latin1_swedish_ci and the encoding in app is set to utf8.
Now the problem is that in some of the actions the same model is being returned in proper format while in the other actions the foreign characters are not being recognized, here is a working example:

```
array(
    'Project' => array(
        'id' => '65',
        'name' => 'Rengøring',
        'address' => 'Nyhavn',
        'post_nr' => '17',
        'city' => 'København',
    )
```

and here is the wrong case:

```
'Project' => array(
            'id' => '65',
            'name' => 'RengÃ¸ring',
            'address' => 'Nyhavn',
            'post_nr' => '17',
            'city' => 'KÃ¸benhavn',
        )
```

Any help or guidance is much appreciated.

Comment: What does your database configuration look like? Does your database connection use UTF8 encoding as well?

Comment: Yes, in database config the encoding is set to utf8.

Comment: Try changing your table(s) to utf8_general_ci

Comment: Read this: http://kunststube.net/frontback/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No proper answers, so I am going to answer it myself.

All that needed to be done was to change all the tables to utf8_general_ci.